# How I can change name in including field in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

How I can change name in request object, if I use sequelize.
I have two models, and Person model include Name model.

Table in db is Names, and my field name is Names.
How I can . change it?

```
Person.findByPk(
    id,
    include: [{
        model: Name
    }]
});
```

Name.Model.js

```
sequelize.define('Name', {
    id: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: type.STRING
    }
});
```

and I get object Person, where one filed is also object

```
Person = {
   ...
   Names: {
      id: 1,
      name: Piter
   }
}
```

I want

```
Person = {
   ...
   name: {
      id: 1,
      name: Piter
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the `as` property in your association wherever you defined it. For example your Person Model could look like this.

```
const Person = sequelize.define('Person', 
    { 
     .
     . //whatever other properties your person has.
     .
     },{});
Person.associate = function(models){
    Person.hasOne(models.Name, {
        as: 'name'
    });
};
```

Edit: More information regarding this subject can be found here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#naming-strategy